# Despite weights being painted correctly, mesh moves in weird ways when I try to animate bones

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

So I'm trying to rig this little wolf up, but the weighting is really weird. Whenever I move any of the bones, despite the weight painting being all correct, it moves the entire mesh rather than just that bone and its children. So in the second picture, as you can see the whole wolf moves, but it really should only be the upper body.

[image: Spine bone weight view]

[image]

I read somewhere that it could be something to do with 'rubber tweak' but I can't find that option anywhere, and I don't even know if that's actually the issue.

Additionally, when I move some other objects that have the weights painted correctly, it doesn't move things enough, like on the tail:

[image]

Finally, it seems that it's only the spine that's causing the whole mesh to move, while other bones just don't move the rig enough.

I used the wolf premade riggify rig and edited it to suit my needs.

Here is the Blender file, better late than never: https://pasteall.org/blend/92d516501ec14a029255840b655c5a6e

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonbots Ok, uploaded! Thanks for the help I had no idea how to upload a blend file.

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping vertices, so go in *Edit* mode and merge by distance. You'll maybe have some corrections to do though.

Comment: So I've removed the doubles (thanks!) however I don't understand when you say to fix spine004 and 5 as they're weighted how I wanted them to move. Unless I'm doing something catastrophically wrong.
I have sort of solved my issue by not using a rigify premade rig, as I made another quadruped model and made the rig myself from scratch and everything moves as I want it to based on the weights I paint. I'm just going to delete the rigify rig and create my own.

Comment: oh ok then....  ;)